# how can i add an fit a large image into a jumbotron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a trivia game for a coding bootcamp and I have a main background image then a jumbotron that displays a timer,question,and 4 clickable answers.  I want in that jumbotron to be a designated image that is saved to the trivia bank question (it's an object).  I can get the image to show but it is over stretched and it takes away the timer/quesitons/buttons.  How can I just put it directly in the background of the jumbotrons size and have it stretch to fit in it properly?
Here is my code:

```
function displayNextQuestion() {
    initialTimer = 21;
    console.log(questionBank[triviaQuestions[counter]].question);
    console.log(questionBank[triviaQuestions[counter]].correctAnswer);
    var questionToDisplay = $('<h2>').addClass('question').text(questionBank[triviaQuestions[counter]].question);
    var answerButtons = $('<div>').addClass('answers');
    var numberOfAnswers = questionBank[triviaQuestions[counter]].answers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfAnswers; i++) {
        var newButton = $('<button>').addClass('answer btn btn-lrg btn-default btn-block').text(questionBank[triviaQuestions[counter]].answers[i])
            .data('index', i).on("click", checkAnswer);
        answerButtons.append(newButton);
    }

    $(".jumbotron").empty().append('<img src =' + questionBank[triviaQuestions[counter]].imageUrl + '>');
    $('#question').empty().append(questionToDisplay, answerButtons);

   // console.log(questionBank[triviaQuestions[counter]].imageUrl);
    run();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use it as a `background-image` instead, use `background-position` in combination with `background-size: cover;`. How you use `background-position` depends on the stuff in the image and what parts you want to be sure to display.

```css
body {
  background: url('http://eskipaper.com/images/large-2.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you're using an image, you can use the `object-fit` property, but it isn't well supported - http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://eskipaper.com/images/large-2.jpg">
```

Comment: I was hoping to keep my main background image and have the second one embedded as it pertains to the trivia question

Comment: @BradGoldsmith what do you mean keep your main background image? You can have multiple background images. If you can create an image element on the page, you can create another element and give it a background...

Comment: ok cool.  I'm brand new to coding so I thought putting it in the jumbotron would be the easiest.  But since there are like 50 or so images that rotate depending on the question what would the code in the .js file look like?

Comment: Take @hungerstar's advice and give me a [mcve] to work with. How the JS looks depends on your markup (html) and existing layout (css)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>TriviaGame</title>
        <!-- We link our html to the Bootstrap CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>STAR WARS TRIVIA</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="row">
                    <p id="timer"></p>
                </div>
                <div id="question">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="start-btn">START</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="reset-btn">RESET</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>




@font-face {
    font-family: distant-galaxy;
    src: url("Distant-Galaxy/DISTGRG_.ttf");
}

body {
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: distant-galaxy;
}

h1 {
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 black, -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black, 0px 1px 0 black, 1px 0px 0 black, 0px -1px 0 black, -1px 0px 0 black, 4px 4px 3px #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.col-md-12 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2%;
}

.col-md-11 {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 2%;
}

.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.container {
    color: grey;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#timer {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

#question {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#start-btn {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#reset-btn {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.btn-block {
    text-align: left;
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: What is this? Is this an answer to your own question? Note that you can edit your question after you've asked it if you need to add relevant information.